# Как убрать все лишнее символы из списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки, list

Есть список: `l = ['<span class="coin-content-name">Ethereum</span>']`

Как мне убрать все лишнее и оставить `"Ethereum"`?

Comment: Откуда список? Используйте специализированные инструменты для html , такие как `BeautifulSoup`, если на входе у вас html документ.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [11]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

In [12]: task = ['<span class="coin-content-name">Ethereum</span>']

In [13]: cleared = [BS(elem, 'html.parser').text for elem in task]

In [14]: cleared
Out[14]: ['Ethereum']
```

Если нужно изменить исходный массив а не получать новый:

```
In [27]: for index, elem in enumerate(task):
    ...:     task[index] = BS(elem, 'html.parser').text

In [28]: task
Out[28]: ['Ethereum']
```

Что такое `BeautifulSoup` [читайте тут.](http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup)

Как работает `enumerate` [читайте тут.](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

r = re.compile('<[^<]+?>')
l = ['<span class="coin-content-name">Ethereum</span>']

cleaned = [r.sub('', s) for s in l]
```